# At the end of my program, why can't it register input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone explain why this does not run?

```
import time
```

Start up menu

```
print ("Before you start the game ensure that you are playing in fullscreen to enhance your gaming experience")
print("")
print ("")
time.sleep(1)
```

This is simply the start up menu

```
print ("Menu")
print ('Instructions: In this game you will be given a series of paths. Using your best judgment you will choose the best path by using the "1" or "2" number keys, followed by pressing the "enter" button')
print ('If the wrong path is selected, there will be consequences of either death, or a lower final score.')
print ('Death will end the game, and you will be forced to start from the beginning of the level.')
time.sleep(1)
print ('If you will like to restart, press "r"')
print ('If you will like to quit, press "q"')
print ('If you  want to play level 1, press "1"')
print ('If you want to play level 2, press "2"')
print ('you cannot restart or quit at this time')
print ('')
print ('')
def levelselection():
    level=""
    while level != "1" and level != "2":
        level = input("Please select a level to play: ")
        return level
#This section below is what I have trouble with. It was working before I added "time sleep and after."
level = levelselection()
if level == "1":
    print("Level 1 selected")
    print ("You and your crew are pinned in the remains of a church on the top floor, along with wounded soldiers. Being fired at by German machine guns, matters will soon only get worse as you see German reinforcements on their way. Find a way to escape with your 9 man crew with minimal casualties.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Do you;")
    print ("1:Order your 6 healthy soldiers to provide cover fire while you try and find a way to escape")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("2:Order 4 soldiers to provide cover fire, while the other two soldiers take care of the wounded and you try and find a way to escape")
    def path1():
        path ==""
        while path !="1" and path!="2":
            path = input("Select a path: ")
```

This is what I have trouble running. It simply does not execute. It does not give me an error message either.

```
    if path == 1:

        print ("The crew provided the cover that was needed to protect you, and you were able to safely make it back with two possible options of escape. The wounded soldiers are starting to bleed out.")
```

Comment: You need to explain your problem better. And your title seems to describe a different problem than the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

a few things that strike me off the cuff:

```
path ==""
```

is a bool. it will return True or False, but it will not set the variable path (which is what you seem to want to do)

```
def path1():
```

you define the function path1() without calling it in your program. It will therefor never run (and will not ask for input either)

Comment: so what do i change to fix it?

Comment: @ElyadK Assign path instead of comparing it, and actually call `path1`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things

```
if level == "1":
print("Level 1 selected")
print ("You and your crew are pinned in the remains of a church on the top floor, along with wounded soldiers. Being fired at by German machine guns, matters will soon only get worse as you see German reinforcements on their way. Find a way to escape with your 9 man crew with minimal casualties.")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Do you;")
print ("1:Order your 6 healthy soldiers to provide cover fire while you try and find a way to escape")
time.sleep(1)
print ("2:Order 4 soldiers to provide cover fire, while the other two soldiers take care of the wounded and you try and find a way to escape")
def path1():
    path ==""
    while path !="1" and path!="2":
        path = input("Select a path: ")
```

def path1() should be its own thing for example

```
def path1(path):
    path ==""
    while path !="1" and path!="2":
        path = input("Select a path: ")

if level == "1":
    print("Level 1 selected")
    print ("You and your crew are pinned in the remains of a church on the top floor, along with wounded soldiers. Being fired at by German machine guns, matters will soon only get worse as you see German reinforcements on their way. Find a way to escape with your 9 man crew with minimal casualties.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Do you;")
    print ("1:Order your 6 healthy soldiers to provide cover fire while you try and find a way to escape")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("2:Order 4 soldiers to provide cover fire, while the other two soldiers take care of the wounded and you try and find a way to escape")
    path = input()
    if path == '1':
        print ("The crew provided the cover that was needed to protect you, and you were able to safely make it back with two possible options of escape. The wounded soldiers are starting to bleed out.")
    path1(path)
```

This works. The problem with your old code was that path1 was in the if statement, path did not have a value,

```
if path == 1:
```

should be

```
if path =='1':
```

and path1 has to take an argument